# Unable to broadcast a large ConcurrentHashMap in Spark 1.5.0

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, broadcast, kryo

I am currently using spark 1.5.0 from cloudera distribution and in my java code trying to broadcast a concurrent hashmap. In the map() function, when I try to read the broadcast variable, I get a NullPointer Exception in the resource manager logs. Can anyone please help me out? I am unable to find any resolution for this. Following is my code snippet:

```
// for broadcasting before calling mapper
final Broadcast<ConcurrentHashMap<ConstantKeys, Object>> constantmapFinal =
                    context.broadcast(constantMap);
```

.......

```
    // In map function
    JavaRDD<String> outputRDD =
                    tempRdd.map(new org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function() {
                        private static final long serialVersionUID =
                                6104325309455195113L;

                        public Object call(final Object arg0)
                                throws **Exception {
                            ConcurrentHashMap<ConstantKeys, Object> constantMap =
                                    constantmapFinal.value(); // line 428
}
    });
```

The exception from resource manager logs:

```
016-11-17 10:40:10 ERROR ApplicationMaster:96 - User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 20, ******(server name)): java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1177)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at com.***.text.fuzzymatch.execute.FuzzyMatchWrapper$2.call(FuzzyMatchWrapper.java:428)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1027)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1109)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1205)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1116)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1095)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:493)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:135)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:17)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:134)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:17)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:729)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoDeserializationStream.readObject(KryoSerializer.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.unBlockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1174)
    ... 21 more
```

This is working for smaller sizes of the map. The map can contain numerous key value pairs based on the input request. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: What is the size of the map , in terms of Gb !

Comment: The size should be in megabytes. Not sure of the exact size, but do we always face this issue while broadcasting? It used to work for smaller requests. Can you please tell me how do I serialize the concurrent hashmap?

Comment: Can anyone please suggest some ideas?